# Are Smart Contracts bytecode encrypted?

Tags: smart-contract, public-key

As the title states, is a smart contract's live machine code encrypted, ciphered, or otherwise shielded? Say a user wants to create a SC to send whatever Ada it receives, at a specified interval, to another wallet (or more than one wallet proportionally). Could that be a workaround to preserve privacy with a published public address?

Answer (score 1):

No, on-chain scripts are completely public and can be decoded easily to reveal the data stored inside the contract.